# Why i can't Rename standard field label 'Contact Name' on Case Object

Tags: case, contact, related-list

Can anyone please tel me why i am not able to rename 'Contact Name' standard field on Case object. I don't see this field under Rename tabs and fields -> Tasks or Rename tabs and fields -->Activities.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot rename it, because is driven by the Contact's translations. You'll find this translation under Rename Tabs and Labels > Contacts. Note that altering this translation will rename all standard lookup fields to contacts, including Case, Contact, Contact Roles, and so on.